# How can i prevent double jumps in new input system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I managed to fix multi jumps with OnCollisionStay but I can't get over with double jumps using new input system. I applied same logic in old input and it works fine but here with new one it keeps double jumping. I tried to disable Jump actions if isGrounded==false but it didn't work(DisableJumpAction). How can I fix it?
Here is my code:

```cs
Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
PlayerControls inputActions;
bool isGrounded;

void OnEnable()
{
    inputActions = new PlayerControls();
    inputActions.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    inputActions.Disable();
}

void Start()
{
    playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Accleration();
    float steerValue = inputActions.PlayerActions.Steer.ReadValue<float>();
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up*steerValue*rotationPower*Time.deltaTime);
    Debug.Log("isGrounded:" + isGrounded);
    DisableJumpAction();
}

void Accleration()
{
    playerRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * playerVelocity);
}

public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (context.performed && isGrounded)
    {
        playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

public void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}

void DisableJumpAction()
{
    if (!isGrounded)
    {
        inputActions.PlayerActions.Jump.Disable();
    }
    else
    {
        inputActions.PlayerActions.Jump.Enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you mean by "double jumps"? Is the jump code running twice? If yes, do these calls happen on the same frame? Have you tried debugging and seeing what's different in the `CallbackContext` for each call?

Comment: So i managed to fix it with OnCollisionExit now it works as i wanted to. I didn't notice a little detail: When i pressed jump button for the first time isGrounded is set to false for 1 frame and then comeback to true(so i can press it again),pressing button once more set bool value to false and don't change unless i hit "Ground" so i can't use jump again. Anyway I appreciate your effort here :)